# how i can change position first and last button in DataPager Control

Tags: asp.net, css, datapager

how i can change the position of elements in my DataPager Control

how i can get this order

<< < 1 2 3 4 5 ...  >   >>

[image]

and this is my code

```
              <asp:DataPager ID="DataPager1" runat="server" PagedControlID="" PageSize="10"  >

        <Fields>
        <asp:NextPreviousPagerField
           ShowFirstPageButton="True"
           ButtonCssClass="" ButtonType="Link"
           FirstPageText="<<" LastPageText="<<"
           NextPageText=">" PreviousPageText="<"
           ShowLastPageButton="True" ShowNextPageButton="True"
           ShowPreviousPageButton="True" />

             <asp:NumericPagerField
                     ButtonType="Link"
                 PreviousPageText="privuse"
                       RenderNonBreakingSpacesBetweenControls="False"/> 

            </Fields>

  </asp:DataPager>
```

Answer (score 0):

ok after search i fund the answer

this my code after edit

```
      <asp:DataPager ID="DataPager1" runat="server" PagedControlID="" PageSize="10"  >

        <Fields>

        <asp:NextPreviousPagerField
             ButtonType="Link"
           LastPageText="<<"
         PreviousPageText="<"
           ShowLastPageButton="True"
             ShowPreviousPageButton="True" />

             <asp:NumericPagerField
                     ButtonType="Link"
                         PreviousPageText="privuse"
                         RenderNonBreakingSpacesBetweenControls="False"
        /> 

            <asp:NextPreviousPagerField
            ShowFirstPageButton="True"
            ButtonType="Link"
           FirstPageText=">>" 
            NextPageText=">"
           ShowNextPageButton="True" />


            </Fields>

  </asp:DataPager>
```